# Prevent creating duplicate entries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I want to randomly create a number of an user id, but it shouldn't be repeated/duplicated.

I wanted to ask if there is a good approach in general if my aim is to INSERT it into in a MySQL database? I don't want to create a new user. Its for another table.

I want to insert random data with random user id's to create test-comment entries users have made, but not I want to display different users. That's why I need it. It's not about autoincrementing with primary key in the main user table. I want to fill out a comment section

Example:

`user_id`: `54,34,30` randomy generated with PHP (`mt_rand()` function). Now I have about 1000 users I want to randomize, but there's still a chance it could be repeated at some point. So let's say now these are the values: `54,54,32`

This means it will insert a same user twiche in further steps, where I `INSERT` this user id in the comment table. 
So I just need another number randomly generated *if* it's already has been generated.

Comment: Uuuuhhhm no. That is terrible. Just use a auto incremental field. Why does it need to be randomized anyway? Also if you really want something random there are much and many better ways.

Comment: No, its not about adding new users. I want to randomly generate user ids for another table, but not a specific user twice. @PeeHaa

Comment: You could try to use a hash from a unique field like the user name.

Comment: But then I'd have to take data from the database first. I just want to generate a number that doesn't repeat itself again in a loop. That's all I need.

Comment: *Why* do you want to generate random ids for another table?

Comment: Because I want to create test entries for a comments table users have made. And I've about dozens of users already. I just want to display it by not showing the same user again. @PeeHaa

Comment: I am still failing to see why it needs to be random. It just makes no sense even without the above comment

Comment: Because iterating would select and insert the same users over and over again?

Comment: So you want to generate usernames and not userids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a GUID, rather than an integer. PHP has built-in methods to create these unique codes.

If you are inserting into a database, I would think that the most robust approach would be to create a primary key, and insert your entries one at a time. Since the DB call will error if you try to insert a duplicate ID, that's an appropriate place to check for an error and choose a different ID if you need to - although if you use a GUID, the chances of duplication are already negligible.

EDIT:

So if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you want to create an array of random arrays of user ids, which are integers between 1-1000, where no two ids are repeated.

I am assuming that performances is not a big issue, since this sounds like test/dummy data. So the simplest way, in my opinion, would be to avoid having to test for an existing id on each id creation, and just shuffle your array.

So, you start with an array of 1000 ids, and then you loop through x number of times, shuffle the array, and slice off a random number of ids from the beginning of the array. Here is some code I have tested. It outputs what I think you want to create.

```
$ids = array();
$commentIds = array();
$numIds = 1000;
$numComments = 10;
for($i=0; $i<$numIds; $i++)
{
    $ids[$i] = $i;
}
for($s=0; $s<$numComments; $s++)
{
    shuffle($ids);
    $num = mt_rand(1,10);
    echo("rand:$num");
    $commentIds[$s] = array_slice($ids,0,$num);
    print_r($commentIds[$s]);
}
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I havent'got enough points to comment on your original question, but it would make it easier for everyone to answer if you show an example of how you would like the final array to end up... do you mean 

[1,4,657,34,12,32]

or do you mean 

[1,3,4,2,5,7,6,8,9]

and do the numbers if the array need to reference a row in another table, or do they need to reference an actual id in another table?

Comment: I edited my question again and posted an example. Maybe this helps to understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific number of users you want to add in, try just incrementing a digit and using that as the username. That way, they're all unique, and you don't have to force kill it after 30 seconds. This should be the easiest way of doing it, unless you need actually random (non-sequential) ids.